# Bose Soundtouch 30II connect with Google Assistant

Tags: spotify, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, soundtouch

I'm using Google Home and Google Chromecast Audio to play Google Play Music or Spotify on my Soundtouch 30 II. It's working fine but I got ONE BIG PROBLEM. I always have to turn my Soundtouch with the remote or the Soundtouch App on to hear the music. It's not that smart if you have to do this step by hand.

Now I'm searching for a solution to integrate my Soundtouch 30 with the Google Assistant. Are there any possibilites like IFTTT, an App, SDK, API or something to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use the [Spotify Connect Web APIs](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/) to control Spotify from your Google Assistant.